# Dynamic-like behavior of base class array in C#

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I have a simple inheritance scheme and an overloaded inherited function:

```
Abstract class Installation
{
abstract void updateValue(int deviceIndex);
}

class InstallationA:Installation
{
override void updateValue(int deviceIndex)

void updateValue (int deviceIndex, byte otherValues)
...
}

class InstallationB: Installation
...
```

In another class, I have an array of Installation(s) that instantiates its values at program startup from an XML document.

My question is how to call the overloading functions updateValue:

```
Installation[] installations;

//instantiation code

installations[0].updateValue (0,0);
```

Declaring the array as `dynamic[] installations` definitely works, but the main class needs to subscribe to some events raised by the Installation classes.

The setup document also contains the type and assembly of the child classes for the purposes of creating a `Type` object, but I'm having difficulties in using it for the purposes of explicit casting.

Is there any way to get the desired behavior?

> Edit:
> Ended up moving the overloaded functions to a different class 'Encoder' that handles the data manipulation and casts the result to object, for a new 'abstract updateValue(int device, object value)' funtion to be overriden by InstallationX in order to cast back to installation specific datatype and update the device value accordingly.

Comment: How do you know if you should call the _type-specific_ method `updateValue(int, byte)` or the shared `updateValue(int)` method? If you should be able to call `updateValue(int, byte)` on all installations, then add an abstract method to the parent class. If you can only call it on 'InstallationA' and not 'InstallationB', then you either need to check the runtime type (with the `is` keyword) or use the Visitor pattern

Comment: This might be helpful to read [link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#circle-ellipse)

Comment: Overloading the shared method was my first thought, but different types of `Installation` have different inputs for `updateValue`, it's basically a cast function that sends the obtained value to an installation, as the name suggests. I'm kinda new to C# so the `as` and `is` keywords flew over my head, is there a way to convert the runtime type with `installations[i] as installations [i].Type`, Type being a `system.reflection.TypeInfo` object that I would store in the base class?

Comment: Create an interface like `IHaveAnOverload` that declares the overloaded function. Then use _pattern matching_:  `if (installations [i] is IHaveAnOverload ov) { ov.updateValue(42, (byte)0); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically no, you can either:

- Put the overload in the base class, and all subtypes will have to override it... which may or may not be appropriate
- Create an overload in the base class that can be optionally overridden in child classes (give it a default implementation in the base class that does nothing or throws (this would require your base class no longer being abstract))... which is probably not a good solution
- Make all of your subtypes use only the version with the extra parameter (perhaps making the function take `void updateValue (int deviceIndex, params byte[] otherValues)` which would at least make the paramater(s) explicitly optional)
- Rethink your design: If your types are not substitutable for your base class (they need an extra function with extra variables) then should they really be subclasses?